# Как создать ограничение на выполнение джобы в ветке, при активном блоке rules?

Tags: gitlab-ci, непрерывная-интеграция, gitlab-runner

Столкнулся с проблемой, что мне необходимо иметь два активных ограничения на выполнение джобы

- Мне необходимо, чтобы джоба посмотрела, имеется ли докерфайл в
  репозитории.
- Джоба должна начать выполнение, только на ветках `develop` и
  `master`, чтобы не запускаться при каждом коммите на фича ветках.

Столкнулся с проблемой того, что блок `rules` нельзя писать вместе с блоком `only`

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - 'dotnet build -c Release -o $CI_PROJECT_DIR/output'
  rules:
    - exists:
        - ci-cd-weather/Dockerfile
    - only:
        - master
        - develop
```

Как можно реализовать необходимую мне логику, в данном пайплайне?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif

Comment: @PavelMayorov к сожалению написание чего-то подобного не помогло, build выполняется при коммитах в любых ветках
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - 'dotnet build -c Release -o $CI_PROJECT_DIR/output'
  rules:
    - exists:
        - ci-cd-weather/Dockerfile
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "master"'

Comment: Так вы же два разных правила написали. А надо одно. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#complex-rules